# Specifying an online image in Sphinx (restructuredtext) format

Tags: image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, directive

Any ideas on how I can refer to an online image while documenting with Sphinx?

This does NOT work:

```
.. image:: http://www.mysite.com/images/someimage.png
```

Gives me:

```
/home/user/proj/2010/11/08/the_forever_war.rst:11: WARNING: nonlocal image URI found: http://www.mysite.com/images/someimage.png
```

Thanks...

Comment: You showed it gives a warning, but there's nothing indicating it does not work. In fact, it indicates there is some support for it (it recognizes an URI) and it's just not recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite embarassing...

As delnan mentioned above in his comment, I'm only getting a Warning.

In my defense, I was trying some quite complicated raw directives before I settled on the image directive, and I was just looking at the output of Sphinx rather on the rendered pages.  When I saw the long output from Sphinx I assumed I hit another error again.

Nonetheless, I'm to blame...  The image loads fine.

Answer (score 20):

As of sphinx 1.4, you can "monkey patch" sphinx from your `docs/conf.py` file like so:

```
import sphinx.environment
from docutils.utils import get_source_line

def _warn_node(self, msg, node, **kwargs):
    if not msg.startswith('nonlocal image URI found:'):
        self._warnfunc(msg, '%s:%s' % get_source_line(node), **kwargs)

sphinx.environment.BuildEnvironment.warn_node = _warn_node
```

A previous version of this answer provided a patch that is incompatible with the latest sphinx 1.4 release[1]. Furthermore, the next release of sphinx should support this configuration option[2]:

```
suppress_warnings = ['image.nonlocal_uri']
```

This will exclude any warnings of 'nonlocal image URI found'.

I found this necessary because I want the `sphinx-build -W` to
emit "warnings as errors" as part of my test & build infrastructure,
to ensure that there are no mistakes in the documentation -- I
know very well that I'm using nonlocal image URI's and I'm OK with
that, but I don't want to ignore the other warnings.

[1] https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2429#issuecomment-210255983

[2] https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2466

Comment: This works, but breaks Sphinx > 1.3 in that warnings cause exceptions (for example if a linked ref does not exist). It needs to be modified slightly to accept kwargs**.

MOre information here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2429

Comment: Here is another monkey patch http://www.dpetzel.info/tips/python/2013/09/24/sphinx-with-external-image-annoyance.html

Answer (score 6):

I use raw html code for this, e.g.:

```
.. raw:: html

   <p style="height:22px">
     <a href="https://travis-ci.org/aio-libs/aiozmq" >
       <img src="https://travis-ci.org/aio-libs/aiozmq.svg?branch=master"/>
     </a>
   </p>
```

Comment: This format allows the external images without the warning, which permits the use of `sphinx-build -W` (turn warnings into errors) in continuous integration suites like travis/tox.

Comment: However, the RST parser on GitHub ignores `raw:: html` :(

Comment: I don't include README.rst in my sphinx docs, and don't expect anybody looking on my /docs directory -- GitHub spoils sphinx markup anyway.

Comment: While this avoids the error, PyPi won't render it. It just dumps the ugly `..raw:: html` statement instead of showing the travis icon. So the monkey patch suggested by @anonymousepythonhacker may be worth the trouble if you're doing this specific thing, which is linking to a travis status image in your README.